# mysql multiple row to single row

Tags: mysql

```
post_id organisation_id
            1   5
            2   57
            3   57
            4   57
            5   58
            6   59
            7   60
            8   61
            8   62
            9   59
            11  57
            12  57
            4   62
```

is there anyway to select post_id, organisation_id1, organisation_id2 in a single row?

Comment: Can you show what your expected results would look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you didn't specify what your table looks like and what would be the outcome that you would like, this is just a guess.

```
SELECT
    a.post_id,
    a.organisation_id,
    b.organisation_id
FROM your_table a
LEFT JOIN your_table b
    ON a.post_id = b.post_id AND a.organisation_id < b.organisation_id
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
select post_id, group_concat(organisation_id)
    from YourTable
    group by post_id;
```

Comment: it returns post_id group_concat(organisation_id)
1 [BLOB - 1B]
2 [BLOB - 2B]
3 [BLOB - 2B]
4 [BLOB - 5B]
5 [BLOB - 2B]
6 [BLOB - 2B]
7 [BLOB - 2B]
8 [BLOB - 5B]
9 [BLOB - 2B]
11 [BLOB - 2B]
12 [BLOB - 2B]