# concat group a SELECT in another SELECT

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Simple question:

There are 2 tables:

1. Genre [name,songID]
2. Song [id,title,userID,status]

   SELECT id,name,title,userID,status FROM songs INNER JOIN genre ON song.id=genre.songID ORDER BY id ASC;

What is the query to get a result from

```
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------+
| id | genre.name  | song.title           | userID | status |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | tech        | Feel it all          |      1 |      1 |
|  2 | tech        | Tester               |      1 |      1 |
|  3 | music       | Sejujurnya           |      1 |      1 |
|  4 | music       | Not Done             |      1 |      1 |
|  5 | life        | Cinta                |      1 |      1 |
|  6 | life        | Feel it all          |      1 |      1 |
|  7 | life        | Not Done             |      1 |      1 |
|  8 | truth       | Tester               |      1 |      1 |
|  9 | tree        | Tester               |      1 |      1 |
| 10 | climb       | Tester               |      1 |      1 |
+----+-------------+----------------------+--------+--------+
```

to

```
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+--------+
| id | genre.name  | song.title                      | userID | status |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+--------+
|  1 | tech        | Feel it all,Tester              |      1 |      1 |
|  2 | music       | Sejujurnya, Not Done            |      1 |      1 |
|  3 | life        | Cinta, Feel it all, Note Done   |      1 |      1 |
|  4 | truth       | Tester                          |      1 |      1 |
|  5 | tree        | Tester                          |      1 |      1 |
|  6 | climb       | Tester                          |      1 |      1 |
+----+-------------+---------------------------------+--------+--------+
```

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4650744/mysql-multiple-row-to-single-row

Comment: I think I see a pattern, the titles from the same genre are imploded, but then what's the deal with `gloom` and `buka`? They aren't even in the original table.

Comment: Take a look at the [GROUP_CONCAT-function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) in MySQL. @Declan_K: your link is for SQL-server, which is slightly different.

Comment: @DaveChen, sorry, had to make up the table. has been edited

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT _is_ what is needed with a "group by" on genre.name

Comment: @MartyMcVry,i tried that, it gives me 1 row of result with all the song title concatenated.

Comment: @d'alar'cop, how's the query looks like?

Comment: Try GROUP_CONTACT - http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: possible duplicate of [Concatenate multiple row into single row](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17160139/concatenate-multiple-row-into-single-row)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [GROUP_CONCAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) with GROUP BY

```
SELECT 
   id,
   genre.name,
   GROUP_CONCAT(title) as title,
   userID,
   status 
FROM 
   songs 
INNER JOIN 
   genre 
ON 
   song.id=genre.songID 
GROUP BY 
   genre.name 
ORDER BY 
   id ASC
```

Comment: Terrific job friend. Awesome.

Comment: @AFwcxx the returned `id` field here would be meaningless here though, as it would refer only to one of the songs, you could change the concat to `GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(id,"-",title)) as title,` so that you can still have the id of the song with the title and just split them up in your code, ie `explode("-",$title);`

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    `Songs`.`id`,
    `Genre`.`Name`,
    GROUP_CONCAT(`Songs`.`Title`) as Title,
    `Songs`.`userID`,
    `Songs`.`status`
FROM
    `Genre`,
    `Songs`
WHERE
    `Genre`.`SongID` = `Songs`.`id`
GROUP BY
    `Genre`.`Name`
```